# Looking for a way to sync/mirror contacts from Office365 to Outlook.com in Outlook 2016 Desktop App

Tags: outlook, office365

I have a peculiar set-up. I need to mirror the contacts on an Outlook 2016 Desktop App that's synced to an Office365 work account, to an Outlook.com account running on that very same Outlook 2016 Desktop App installation. Essentially when the Outlook Desktop App gets an updated contact from the Salesforce for Outlook add-in, I want that contact to automatically one-way sync to the Outlook.com account running on that same Outlook Desktop App.

I looked and really can't find a similar scenario using these accounts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ReliefJet Essentials](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials) for this. Professional Edition provides the command line you can use to run manually or schedule to remove existing contacts on your Outlook.com account and copy all required contacts from Office365 account to Outlook.com.